# hide xcode instrument functions source code but still allow other user to use the functions?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I wrote some functions for automation scripts running in instruments. They are all in .js files. How I can hide the source code so other users can't view how I code the functions but still able to use the functions?